# Is it possible in C to have a struct or union of functions?

Tags: c, function, struct, unions

Is there any way, whether union, struct, or something else, to have a group of functions?

```
typedef struct {
    //ERROR
    int sqr(int i) {
        return i * i;
    }
    //ERROR
    int cube (int i) {
        return i * i * i;
    }
} test;
```

Comment: Possible, but not this way. You can have *pointers* to functions in a struct. Unions won't make much sense though.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Unions make sense for the other cases that unions make sense for, where one sometimes wants a pointer to one type of function and sometimes a pointer to another type of function. E.g., one might be doing some parsing with YACC and need to call or point to different kinds of functions in different situations.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Agree.

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway?

Comment: Trying to make a collection of functions, in any way, if possible.

Comment: Why do you want a collection of functions?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Well, people are collecting coins, post stamps and other weird things.. why not to collect functions? :)

Comment: @Chirstian Gibbons Ok,    I confess. I want object-oriented C, but C++ is a little too bizarre in some ways.

Comment: It's not as bizarre as trying to do it in C will be :-)

Comment: @rici Depends on how deep you want to go.  If you stop at including function-pointers in structs then it won't be so bad.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons they are very useful if you want to [emulate vtables](http://cecilsunkure.blogspot.com/2012/08/object-oriented-c-virtual-table-vtable.html)

Comment: @DavidRanieri It's been a few years since I read Randy Gaul's coding blog.  This time around, I'm noticing his unfortunate use of identifiers beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fields in structs can be function pointers:

```
struct Interface {
    int (*eval)(int i);
};
```

You cannot define the functions in the struct body, but you can assign functions with the same signature to the struct fields:

```
int my_sqr(int i) {
    return i * i;
}

int my_cube(int i) {
    return i * i * i;
}

struct Interface squarer = { my_sqr };
struct Interface cuber = { my_cube };
```

Then call the fields like a normal function:

```
printf("%d\n", squarer.eval(4));    // "16"
printf("%d\n", cuber.eval(4));      // "64"
```